# How can I insert a table of explanations in Word 2002?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a long text, like in the example, that requires a lot of explanations.
How can I automatically order the numbers [1], [2], [3] in the text and also in the table of explanations? (I use Word 2002).

Example:

> "*The second experiment in the workshop was made in the presence of the Chairman[1], the purpose being to demonstrate that the wings, having a spread of 17 meters[3], were sufficiently strong to support the weight of the apparatus[2]. With this aim in view, 14 sliding supports were placed under each one of these, representing imperfectly the manner in which the wings would support the machine in the air ...*"

Explanations:

1. Chairman, a representative of the army.
2. The apparatus had a weight of about 400 kg.
3. 17 m = 55.77 ft

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do these explanation numbers need to repeat, e.g. you have a chunk of text, then several explanations numbered 1,2,3..., then another chunk, with more explanations numbered 1,2...? Or what? Do the numbers have to be formatted like [1]?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want: "Do these explanation numbers need to repeat, e.g. you have a chunk of text, then several explanations numbered 1,2,3..., then another chunk, with more explanations numbered 1,2... (YES) Do the numbers have to be formatted like [1]? (YES)". If you know how to do these things please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

- your document has multiple "chunks"
- in each chunk there might be 0 or more explanations
- if chunk A has three explanations and chunk B has 2 explanations,
  they should be numbered [1],[2],[3], then [1],[2]
- you need the format to be [1]

You can use SEQ fields to achieve this. But you will need to select and update those SEQ fields - Word does not update their results automatically.

You could put the following SEQ field at the beginning of each chunk:

```
{ SEQ exp \r0 \h }
```

(Use ctrl-F9 to insert  each pair of the special field code braces {} - you cannot just type them on the keyboard). You don't have to use "exp" - you could use "e", or "fred", etc.

Then insert the following at each point where you need a reference:

```
{ SEQ exp \#[0] }
```

At the end of the chunk you put another

```
{ SEQ exp \r0 \h }
```

Then you start each explanation with

```
{ SEQ exp \#[0] }
```

or if you need a tab after every [n], you could put a tab character in the formatting option, e.g.

```
{ SEQ exp \#"[0]<tab>" }
```

where you insert an actual tab character where I have put `<tab>`.

You can use alt-F9 to toggle between "field code view" and "field results view", and select the document (e.g. ctrl-A) then press F9 to update all the fields in it.

If you need more automatic sequencing, you could do the following.

At the beginning of each chunk, insert

```
{ SEQ ch \h }{ SEQ exp \r0 \h }
```

For each explanation, put the following in the body of the chunk

```
{ QUOTE { SEQ exp \#[0] }{ SET "exp{ SEQ ch \c }_{ SEQ exp \c }" "{ SEQ exp \c \#"[0]<tab>" }the text of your explanation" } }
```

(Notice that *all* the { } have to be the special field code pairs, not just the outermost ones. To insert these reasonably easily, you could create an autotext with some "stub" text and insert the whole nested field in one go)

At the end of the chunk, put

```
{ SEQ exp \r0 \h }
```

Then for each explanation, you will need one of these for each explanation (in other words, you will have to do that manually, or you could perhaps have a set of fields that would let you allow for (say) up to 10 explanations.)

```
{ "exp{ SEQ ch \c }_{ SEQ exp }" }
```

Once you have worked out how this stuff works, you will see that it is possible to vary the way this stuff works in many ways.

However, if you need even more automation than that, you could consider this (I think it is harder). It uses TC fields to define the text, and a TOC field to display the results. But this is much more difficult to maintain, because you have to insert a different bookmark name for every chunk in your document, you may have to respond to prompts for every TOC, and so on. You also have almost no control over the formatting and layout of your explanatory text.

But to do that you could do this:

At the beginning of each chunk, put

```
{ SEQ exp \r0 \h }
```

For each explanation reference in the chunk, use the following set of field codes. (It's probably best to save a "stub" as an Autotext and use the Autotext mechanism to insert them)

```
{ SEQ exp \#[0] }{ TC "{ SEQ exp \#"[0]<tab>" }your explanation text" \l 9 }
```

Select the chunk and use Insert->Bookmark to insert a unique bookmark name for the chunk. Let's say it is "chunk_xyz".

After the chunk, insert the following field code

```
{ TOC \f \l 9-9 \b chunk_xyz }
```

The `\l 9, \l 9-9` indicate the paragraph style (in this case, TOC 9) that Word will apply to your explanation texts. Choosing something that is not used by any other TOC should allow you to modify the paragraph layout a little. Unfortunately, trying to format the text inside the TC fields does not work because Word uses the TC text to generate plain text for the TOC field.

Comment: How can I link a field like this { SEQ exp \#[0] } to an explanation. Your method always orders, in the chunk of text, the numbers from [1] to [n], however, in the list with explanations, after an update, the correspondence between the numbers and explanations is lost.

Comment: Assuming I have understood you correctly, I have added some more stuff that may help, and a slightly different approach. FWIW I feel sure I have covered this ground before somewhere on this site - if so, it will probably be worth finding.